# Alternatives to embedded credentials in Chrome for links to third party sites?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

My goal is to have a link a visitor can click and then be redirected and logged into a site with basic authentication. We currently use embedded credentials for this on a couple of web pages not hosted by us, [but embedded credentials are no longer supported in Chrome](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/lx-U_JR2BF0/discussion). I've been investigating alternatives to passing credentials in the URL (ie `https://user:password@website.com`), and so far haven't found a solution that's better than the following:

```
var url = 'https://www.third-party-website.com';
var username = 'my-username';
var password = 'my-password';
var encodedAuth = window.btoa(username + ':' + password); 

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true,
  },
  headers: {
   "Authorization": "Basic " + encodedAuth
  },
  complete: function (result) {
   window.location.href = url;
  },
  error: function (req, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Which gives me the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.third-party-website.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://my-website.com' is therefore not allowed access.

[Based on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource), I think I would need access to the third party's server to set its `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to allow my domain. Are there any other alternatives for me if I can't change the header on the third party server? Or is my AJAX request not formatted correctly?

Comment: Your ajax is configured properly. Might be able to accompish what you need using a proxy. Cookies for other site may be problematic though

Answer (score 0):

You may want to setup an page on your own website as a proxy
and post the username + password to your proxy using something like this in js
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

```
$usr = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
```

[How to setup curl with auth](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-sending-username-password/)